# Adding spring application module as jar to another springboot standalone application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-8

Want to add spring application into springboot standalone application.

I have 1 project which contains pojo, dao, service [core-module]in it. and I have added that core-mdodule to web-app module that uses spring boot. It is working properly.
Now I want to add core-module to another springboot standalone application. I want to make a jar of standalone project. so that I can schedule it to run.

Java - 8 is used in this project.

All services mentioned in above image have @service annotation on it and dao has @repository annotation in it. But still it gives error of unsatisfied dependency. When I checked jar file generated of standalone project it doesnot have core-modules code.

Standalone module pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.standalone</groupId>
    <artifactId>StandaloneApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.version>2.3.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
          
    <dependencies> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
    <build>
        <finalName>api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom file of core-modules

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.version>2.3.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.19.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        // ..some more dependencies
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

standalone application 1 and only file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.core"})
@EntityScan("com.fc.backend")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project.core", "com.project.standalone"})
public class StandaloneApp{
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()); 
           
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.location", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/properties/application.yml");
        SpringApplication.run(StandaloneApp.class, args);
        StandaloneApp testObj = new StandaloneApp();
        testObj.testRunMethod();
    }

    public void testRunMethod(){
        System.out.println(".........Method Starts........");
        
        UserService uService = new UserService();
        List<User> activeUser = uService.getAllActiveUsers();
            for (User user : activeUser) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(user.getWritePath()) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(user.getFtpPath())) {
                    System.out.println(".........name........"+distributor);
                }
            }
        System.out.println(".........Method Ends........");
    }
}
```

Running standalone project is giving below error:

```
2023-06-28 18:18:08.939  WARN 17692 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'markupTypeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dcpsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'distributorClientProductSelectionService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'exchangeRateService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exchangeRateService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'distributorDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'distributorDaoImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.fc.backend.distributor.dao.impl.DistributorDaoImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@31cefde0]
2023-06-28 18:18:08.939  INFO 17692 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: New if only [that would be in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.build.use-a-spring-boot-application-as-dependency). A Spring Boot application has a defined structure which isn't a regular jar. So either you need to ditch the maven plugin for spring boot in that project so it becomes a regular jar or follow the link and create 2 artifacts, 1 regular jar and 1 spring boot jar. That being said, stop mixing jars from different version of Spring Boot (your maven plugin is different) and use the proper starters instead of single deps.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I have changed version to become same in both project. Still error persists. I removed for maven-plugin from build tag of standalone pom still the same error.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why it doesn't work. I am assuming "com.project.core" is the correct package name from the core-module. I've had to do something similar in the past. I created my own spring boot starter to achieve it. Here's the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.custom-starter) on how to create custom starters.

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma, thanks for you answer I found that on dependency has provided scope that is used in dao that is giving error now it is solved.